# How to avoid unefficent network data usage via CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

WWDC 2014 Advanced Cloudkit Video suggests: *Every time it receives a push, it should go check the notification collection to find anything it might have missed.*

I do the same, but if in very short time 2 updates occures on the same record, I will get 2 push notifications, and each will use network twice, and so `notificationChangedBlock` will get called 2x2 = 4 times, but relevant is only 2 (or 0 if no notification was missed).

This is not efficient, what you do differently?

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    Utility.checkNotifications()
}

class func checkNotifications() {

    let defaultContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicDatabase = defaultContainer.publicCloudDatabase

    let fnco = CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation(previousServerChangeToken: previousChangeToken)
    fnco.notificationChangedBlock = {notification in

        readNotificationIDs.append(notification.notificationID)
        if previousChangeToken != nil {
            Utility.processNotification(notification)
        }
    }
    fnco.fetchNotificationChangesCompletionBlock = {serverChangeToken, error in

        previousChangeToken = serverChangeToken
        let op = CKMarkNotificationsReadOperation(notificationIDsToMarkRead: readNotificationIDs)
        op.start()
    }
    defaultContainer.addOperation(fnco)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this old trick:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(fetchPendingNotifications) object:nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(fetchPendingNotifications) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0f];
```